# Why does Java concurrent processing not work with newly instantiated objects, while it works with deserialized objects of the same class?

Tags: java, multithreading, serialization, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I am using `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` to perform a concurrent calculation on all available processing resources. In the code below an instance of `MyProcessor` class in its `performParallelProcessing` method creates a number of `ProcessingExecutor` class instances and submits them to the `ExecutorService` instance expecting to get the corresponding callbacks.

The processing happens in `performProcessing` method of `ProcessingExecutor` class. The data that I use for processing are object instances of class `ComputationData`. They either can be retrieved from the file system (if serialized data exist), or can be initialized as new instances.

Here is the problem:

In the case if `ComputationData` object instances are deserialized from the file system, the concurrent processing executes as I expect it to do. It runs in parallel on all the processing cores, occupying 100% of the processing resources.

In the case if `ComputationData` object instances are newly initialized, the concurrent processing does not execute as I expect. It runs as if it was a single-threaded execution, occupying around 15% of the processing resources.

As I can guess, something is wrong with my newly initialized `ComputationData` object instances. But I don't know what can be wrong with them and why the concurrency does not work for them while it works for their serialized->deserialized versions. Any hints or ideas will be greatly appreciated.

```
public class MyProcessor {
    private boolean processingFinished = false;

    public void performParallelProcessing(){
        int count = 0;
        boolean continueProcessing = true;

        int nrOfProcessors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nrOfProcessors);

        while (continueProcessing){
            ProcessingExecutor task = new ProcessingExecutor(count);
            task.setCaller(this);
            es.submit(task);
            count++;

            if (!processingFinished){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                }
                catch(SecurityException | InterruptedException e){
                    //Exception handling
                }
            }
            else{
                continueProcessing = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void callBack(ProcessingResult result) {
        if(result.allDataProcessed()){
            this.processingFinished = true;
        }
    }
}

public class ProcessingExecutor implements Callable {
    private MyProcessor processor;
    private int count;

    public ProcessingExecutor(int count){
        this.count = count;
    }

    public Object call() {
        ProcessingResult result = null;
        try {
            result = performProcessing();
        }
        catch (SecurityException e) {
            //Exception handling
        }

        processor.callBack(result);     
        return null;
    }

    public void setCaller(MyProcessor processor) {
       this.processor = processor;
    }

    public MyProcessor getCaller() {
        return this.processor;
    }

    private ProcessingResult performProcessing(){
        ComputationData data = null;

        if(serializedDataExist()){
            data = getSerializedData(count);
        }
        else{
            data = initializeNewData(count);
        }

        ProcessingResult result = new ProcessingResult(data, count);
        return result;
    }

    private ComputationData getSerializedData(int count){
        ComputationData data = null;
        // code to retrieve a ComputationData object from the file system
        // based on 'count' value.
        return data;
    }

    private ComputationData initializeNewData(int count){
        ComputationData data = null;
        // code to initialize a new instance of ComputationData class
        // based on 'count' value.
        return data;
    }

    private boolean serializedDataExist(){
        boolean dataFound = false;
        // code to verify whether serialized ComputationData objects are
        // present on the file system.
        return dataFound;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you think the problem is with the `ComputationData` class, it would be a good idea to include it in the question.

Comment: have you used a profiler to try to track down what's happening?  my guess is that the deserialization is what takes all the time so when you aren't doing that, it completes much more quickly and requires less cpu

Comment: Serialization is a CPU intensive process while allocating a new object is not comparatively. How do you know that first one is utilizing 100% resources ? Are you just looking at your task manager ?

Comment: @Arkantos, yes I am looking at the task manager and it does show ~100% and ~15% for the two cases. In addition I also compare the overal execution time (e.g. around 500 seconds) of my concurrent implementation with the execution time of a single-threaded code that I also have and that does the same processing. In case of the "newly initialized objects" the concurrent implementation shows the same execution time as the single-threaded one. In case of the "desirialized objects" the concurrent performance is significantly (order of magnitude) faster than the single-threaded one.

Comment: Do you mean to say that code with deserializing objects is faster than code with new instances ? It won't be like that unless you do something really slow during initialization may be in constructor

Comment: @MartinSerrano I have not used a profiler (sounds like a good idea, indeed), it has been 6 years that I didn't touch java programming and I am a long way behind with the state of the art of java itself and with the tools (e.g. a profiler). I though that I may be missing something that is very obvious for those who are familiar with `java.util.concurrent` package. I'm sorry if I sound too naive :-)

Comment: @Arkantos, no the "deserialized objects" case is obviously much slower than the "newly instantiated objects" case. It is the concurrent version of "deserialized objects" case that is much faster then the single-threaded version of "deserialized objects" case. While the concurrent version of "newly instantiated objects" case shows the same execution time as the single-threaded version of "newly instantiated objects" case.

Comment: @biziclop, yes you are right. I will present `ComputationData` class tomorrow. It has a number of array-type attributes, some of them `ArrayList<X>`, where `X` class can be seen as an aggregation of `float` values, some are just `float[]` arrays. All of `X` implement `Serializable` interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need the `Thread.sleep(50)` ? This is what's making the concurrent execution into a sequential one, especially if each each computation is <= 50 ms. My guess is that deserialization time + computation time is longer than 50 ms, which would be why in the deserialized objects scenario you have more CPU activity, because you'd have effectively multiple tasks running at the same time in the executor threads. You should try without `Thread.sleep(50)` or at least with a much smaller timeout.

Comment: Bravo et merci! `Thread.sleep(50)` is indeed the reason. And your explanation is correct. Though, if I remove the sleep completely, then for some reason the execution never finishes. Introducing a very short sleep (e.g. `Thread.sleep(1)`) allows the execution to finish as expected. For now I do not yet understand the reason, why the sleep is necessary.

Comment: One possible problem is that you are reading `processingFinished` from the main thread and setting its value from one or more executor threads. You should synchronize all accesses to this variable, for example `synchronized(this) { processingFinished = true; }`. It's probably easier to use a synchronized getter and setter.

Comment: This was also a useful note explaining the reason correctly! Indeed, the reason for non-finishing execution in the case of no sleep was an absence of synchronization. My actual code is more complex than the samples that I presented. `Thread.sleep()` actually assured synchronization of the reading of input data from the standard input stream. But, you are right, it is much more efficient if I use `synchronized` getters and setters. Thank you very much for your useful comments!